# Apache Secure Location without AuthUserFile

Tags: apache2, basic-authentication

I have enabled the status mod

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>
    ExtendedStatus On
    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        #Order deny,allow
        #Deny from all
        #Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

can i add an basic authentication without AuthUserFile? i just want to define username an password in my config file